# Problems starting plexmediaserver on Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: init.d, plex

I have recently installed plexmediaserver 64-bit from the plex site on my Kubuntu 15.04 laptop and am unable to start. I believe it is in the change from how init scripts work?

If you look at the guide for Plex it says to execute `/etc/init.d/plexmediaserver start` once you have installed it for the first time.

It appears  that `/etc/init.d/plexmediaserver` is an invalid symlink or something?

Not sure where to go to help troubleshoot this...

Comment: It looks like Plex needs to be updated or fixed for systemd?  https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/152214-systemd-service-file-for-ubuntu-package/

Comment: That discussion was updated in May 2015 and now says that the Ubuntu plex package _has been_ updated for systemd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above script was already on my system and it still was not working. Upgrading to 0.9.12.4.1192 fixed all issues with systemd.

Answer (score 12):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 15.04

Resolved it by creating a new file: `/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service`

Afterwards, pasted the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Plex Media Server for Linux
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR=/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support"
Environment=PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_HOME=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver
Environment=PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_MAX_PLUGIN_PROCS=6
Environment=PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_TMPDIR=/tmp
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver
Environment=LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
Environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}"'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Server'
Type=simple
User=plex
Group=plex
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run, `sudo service plexmediaserver start`

Plex should start normally and you should be able to access it through: http://127.0.0.1:32400/web

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2y4pwm/ubuntu_to_switch_to_systemd_next_monday_brace_for/cp75472)

Comment: The `/bin/sh -c` wrapping in `ExecStart` is wholly unnecessary, and indeed a mismatch for `Type=simple`.

Comment: i did this and now i get : chris@mediaserver2:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
Failed to start plexmediaserver.service: Unit plexmediaserver.service failed to load: Bad message. See system logs and 'systemctl status plexmediaserver.service' for details.

Comment: @JdeBP I just verified that the change you suggest does **not** work.

Comment: Not having a wholly unnecessary and mismatched extra shell process works just fine for many other people, including a lot of Arch Linux users it seems. You've botched it somehow.