# Udev and systemd are broken any help would be appreciated

Tags: apt, udev, systemd, 15.04

I cannot configure udev or systemd

```
cam@banowsky:~/rails/lo/db$ sudo dpkg --configure udevSetting up udev (219-     4ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'plex' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket     
/com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'mongodb' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script  `mongodb'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongodb'
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket    /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'plexmediaserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and plex if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service plex at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping plex depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all'   which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-10-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
udev
cam@banowsky:~/rails/lo/db$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure udev
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: udev is broken or not fully installed
```

I have also run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure udev
dpkg-reconfigure systemd
susudodo apt-get install -f
```

The failure occurs at this point

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-10-generic
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://asciinema.org/a/18014 This will give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: A similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/618275/ and related ones are http://askubuntu.com/questions/617575/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/600026/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem:

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'S85vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service ondemand and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```

The problem was caused by the installation of a third party vpn client. I undid its installation and everything went back to normal.

So looking at your error message, it might be that one of 'plexmediaserver', 'plex' and 'mongodb' is causing the trouble. May be removing those packages solves the problem.