# Uninstall broken Plex Media Server from 15.04

Tags: uninstall, upstart

I tried installing Plex Media Server on Ubuntu 15.04 but it didn't work because of the migration to systemd from Upstart. Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to uninstall it now either, since the callbacks error out and prevent dpkg from uninstalling the package. Is there a way to forcibly uninstall the package?

Here's what happens when I attempt to uninstall:

```
leslie@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --remove plexmediaserver
(Reading database ... 191366 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing plexmediaserver (0.9.12.0.1071-7b11cfc) ...
Synchronizing state for plexmediaserver.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d plexmediaserver defaults
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'plexmediaserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d plexmediaserver disable
update-rc.d: error: plexmediaserver Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
OK
Synchronizing state for plexmediaserver.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d plexmediaserver defaults
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'plexmediaserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d plexmediaserver enable
update-rc.d: error: plexmediaserver Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver
```

/var/lib/dpkg/info/plexmediaserver.prerm:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ `cat /etc/issue|cut -d"." -f1|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` -gt 14 ];
then
  systemctl stop plexmediaserver.service
  systemctl disable plexmediaserver.service
else
  if [ -e "/etc/init/plexmediaserver.conf" ]; then
  stop plexmediaserver || :
  fi
fi
```

/var/lib/dpkg/info/plexmediaserver.postrm:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_makeshlibs
if [ "$1" = "remove" ]; then
    ldconfig
fi
# End automatically added section
```

Comment: Add the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/plexmediaserver.prerm` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/plexmediaserver.postrm`. Try commenting out any calls to `update-rc.d` in them.

Comment: I added the contents of those two files. No reference to update-rc.d in them.

Comment: Try commenting out the call to `systemctl disable`.

Comment: Aha, that did the trick. Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: A similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/617575/ and a related one is http://askubuntu.com/questions/600026/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in the output:

> ```
> Synchronizing state for plexmediaserver.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
> ```

suggests that `systemctl` is calling `update-rc.d`, and the only plausible line that does this is:

> ```
> systemctl disable plexmediaserver.service
> ```

Commenting it out or cancelling out the error from it should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, that helped me removing lxdm on the same way, commenting a update-rc.d lxdm disable call