# status: Unable to connect to Upstart:

Tags: services, docker

When I want to check if a service is running, in my case if docker service is running, I typed:

```
sudo status docker
```

And as output I've got:

```
status: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message means your Ubuntu is not using Upstart.

From Ubuntu 15.04, systemd is now the default init process instead of Upstart, and as a result some commands have changed.

With systemd, you can instead check the status of, for example, docker with the command:

```
service docker status
```