# update-rc.d: warning: missing LSB keyword

Tags: startup-applications

Hi tried to add my nagios service to the runlevel 1-5 (or at least 2).
But when I used the command

```
sudo update-rc.d nagios default
```

I received the error

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/nagios missing LSB keyword 'default-start'

update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/nagios missing LSB keyword 'default-stop'

usage: update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
   update-rc.d [-n] <basename> defaults [NN | SS KK]
   update-rc.d [-n] <basename> start|stop NN runlvl [runlvl] [...] .
   update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
            -n: not really
            -f: force

The disable|enable API is not stable and might change in the future.
```

Since there are only symbolic links in the /etc/rc2.d folder my next idea would be to just simple create a symbolic link to the binary.
But I am not sure if this is a good idea since there must be a reason for a existing update-rc.d program?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## the all-important letter 's'

You've missed the obvious.  You typed

```
update-rc.d nagios default
```

and the command told you that the syntax was

```
update-rc.d [-n]  defaults [NN | SS KK]
```

Note the spelling: `defaults`

## broken nagios LSB headers

As for the warnings about the nagios LSB headers:  As I've said at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200281/5132 and at https://askubuntu.com/a/617822/43344, you're far better off *not starting from there in the first place*.  The [Nagios Enterprises supplied System 5 `rc` script](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/master/daemon-init.in) doesn't have a proper, complete, set of LSB headers.  But it's foolish to waste time fixing it.

*You're using Ubuntu Linux*.  You have upstart here with version 14, and you'll have systemd if you ever upgrade.  *Begin* with a systemd unit file, or an upstart job file.

- For systemd, you could do worse than start with [this `nagios.service` file written by David Kowis](https://github.com/dkowis/smgl-systemd/blob/master/nagios.service).
- For upstart, you could do worse than start with the `nagios.conf` file written by Remy van Elst that is part of a guide to installing nagios on your very version of Ubuntu.

(If you really must: The Debian people have fixed it in their nagios3 source package and so has someone named "djibril".)

## Further reading

- Remy van Elst (2014-08-15). "Setup the upstart script".  [*Nagios 4 + Nagiosgraph installation on Ubuntu*](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Nagios_Core_4_Installation_on_Ubuntu_12.04.html).  raymii.org.
- djibril (2014).  ["Démarrage de Nagios"](http://djibril.developpez.com/tutoriels/linux/nagios-pour-debutant/#LII-G). *Installation et configuration de Nagios pour débutants*.  Developpez.com.

Comment: OK thanks.
The command worked now with `sudo update-rc.d thruk defaults` but with the nagios service I still get the LSB error.