# Problems updating plexmediaserver on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: init.d, systemd, plex

I followed the guidelines in this post [- @ -](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600026/problems-starting-plexmediaserver-on-kubuntu-15-04/617015?noredirect=1#comment870213_617015) but it seems that this has brought about a new problem, I can no longer update plex due to the error "E: The package plexmediaserver needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." This is a very annoying problem as I am unable to open Synaptic due to the same error, can someone please find a fix for this.

Comment: Download it from here: https://plex.tv/downloads. Then do `sudo dpkg -i plexmediaserver-[whichever version].deb`. Then, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and dpkg will probably stop complaining.

Comment: That didn't seem to work, it put this out after the second command - http://pastebin.com/VgHmE9Dg

Comment: The server is built to be controlled by Upstart. Your 15.04 system does no longer use Upstart but uses Systemd instead. Create a `plexmediaserver.service` file as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/600026/problems-starting-plexmediaserver-on-kubuntu-15-04).

Comment: Thats what broke it - the link is in my question to the same post, it's in between the -@-, and its most likely the problem. Also use the answer button to answer its a lot clearer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the solution for removing plex error i followed this instruction

http://www.ihaveapc.com/2011/10/fix-annoying-the-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it-error-in-linux-mint-ubuntu/

sudo rm -f /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver &&

sudo dpkg --purge --force-all plexmediaserver

sudo apt-get purge plexmediaserver

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/plexmediaserver

sudo userdel plex

sudo rm /etc/init/plexmediaserver.conf

sudo rm /etc/default/plexmediaserver

After all the above steps I have downloaded from software center plex. that vertion is so old. Then i upgraded to this vertion plexmediaserver_0.9.11.7.803-87d0708_amd64 this vertion is kind of working okay.

And NOW EVERYTHING WORKING PERFECT FOR ME