# Im trying to find out why plex isnt starting on boot any more, ubuntu 15.04 server

Tags: server

I looked into /var/log/boot but all it says is

> - Starting Plex Media Server[122G[ OK ]

Is there somewhere else to look? 
running

> sudo service plexmediacenter start

loads the program, but I have to do it manually now after upgrading to 15.04.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there somewhere else to look?

Yes:

- `systemctl status plexmediacenter`
- `systemctl status plexmediaserver`
- `journalctl -e -x`

> I have to do it manually now

`systemctl preset plexmediacenter` is probably going to be your friend.  But that's getting ahead of yourself.  Read the logs first.

## Further reading

- [Problems starting plexmediaserver on Kubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600026/)